# How Many Degrees of Freedom of a Baseball Pitch?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, degrees-of-freedom

My class asks why a major league pitch is so difficult to hit.  A ball is pitched with adjustable velocity and trajectory, the latter dictated partly by spin (or on rare occasions, lack of spin).  What are the degrees of freedom either exhibited by the ball or available to the pitcher?  Does the swing of the bat have similar degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 0):

Degrees of freedom are not the problem. It's reaction time.

A fast pitch (100mph) takes 400 ms to travel from the pitcher to the striker. It takes a human about 300 ms from the brain's decision to move, to the time the bat actually starts to move.

So the batter has just 100ms to figure out what the ball is doing before being committed to making a particular movement that will attempt to hit it.

Of course professional baseball players do not have to figure out what the ball will do "from first principles" for every pitch, because they have already seen thousands of pitches and *learned* how to extrapolate from the first 100ms of the ball's movement (and also from the pitcher's movements before releasing the ball) to the rest of the ball's trajectory.

The importance of learning was demonstrated in an experiment in 2004, where Albert Pujols (one of the top-ranked *baseball* hitters) faced  Jennie Finch (an Olympic medalist and top-ranked *softball* pitcher). Pujol's success rate was low (and the same was true for other top-rank baseball players), because he did *not* have a deep pattern-recognition memory of what softball pitches look like.

Compared with other animals, human reaction times are slow. For example birds such as starlings which fly in large flocks have reaction times of around 80ms, not 300ms, to avoid collision with other birds.

It is interesting to compare baseball and cricket. The fastest cricket bowling is slower than baseball pitching (anything over 90mph is exceptional) and the distance travelled is longer (22 yards) but the ball's motion is more complicated because usually it is bounced from the ground rather than traveling only through the air.

On the other hand, the region in space which counts as a "legal" delivery of the ball is much larger than in baseball, and the batsman can move anywhere in an attempt to hit it (though moving may have consequences after a miss!)

As a result, an aggressive batter will often start to  run *towards* the bowler starting before the ball has left the bowler's hand, which reduces the total reaction time available but also reduce the variability of where the ball will be. However the bowler can react to the batter's movements and change the trajectory of the ball to compensate for them.

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive answer, but it addressed my preamble, not my question.  The class's interest is in the degrees of freedom of a thrown projectile.  Vx, Vy, Vz and X, Y, Z - are these the degrees of freedom?  How is spin accounted for?  Are the fluid dynamics of the air a degree of freedom?  The answer given does not apply to a batter responding to a 30 m/s knuckleball.  I'd bet that the reaction time is much smaller since a well-thrown knuckleball does not follow a smooth path but rather jumps randomly just before it reaches home plate.